# how to make search bar bigger

Tags: html, css

I am working on a search box here and here's my HTML:

```
 <div class="masthead text-center">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 mx-auto">
                    <h1>Search for it</h1>
                    <p class="lead text-muted">Sed eget orci eleifend enim mattis suscipit. Suspendisse potenti non ipsum.</p>
                    
<form action="">
  <input type="search">
  <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
</form>


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and here's my CSS:

```
form{
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    transition: all 1s;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: white;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 25px;
    border: 4px solid white;
    padding: 5px;
}

input{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;;
    height: 42.5px;
    line-height: 30px;
    outline: 0;
    border: 0;
    display: none;
    font-size: 1em;
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

.fa{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 42.5px;
    height: 42.5px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: #07051a;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    transition: all 1s;
}

form:hover{
    width: 200px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

form:hover input{
    display: block;
}

form:hover .fa{
    background: #07051a;
    color: white;
}
```

Right now this appears to be small. I want to make my search bar as big as this and the icons also big to the center:

Whenever that I tried to modify the padding it's actually destroyign the radius.

Here's my JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/xfcLt3uw/

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to increase width in `form:hover`.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600&display=swap');

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
  display: block;
}
body {
  line-height: 1;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
}
ol, ul {
  list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
  quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}


body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background: #07051a;
}

form{
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    transition: all 1s;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: white;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 25px;
    border: 4px solid white;
    padding: 5px;
}

input{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;;
    height: 42.5px;
    line-height: 30px;
    outline: 0;
    border: 0;
    display: none;
    font-size: 1em;
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

.fa{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 42.5px;
    height: 42.5px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: #07051a;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    transition: all 1s;
}

form:hover{
    width: 350px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

form:hover input{
    display: block;
}

form:hover .fa{
    background: #07051a;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
    <div class="masthead text-center">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 mx-auto">
                    <h1>Search for it</h1>
                    <p class="lead text-muted">Sed eget orci eleifend enim mattis suscipit. Suspendisse potenti non ipsum.</p>
                    
<form action="">
  <input type="search">
  <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
</form>


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is your modified [**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/6uf9nb4x/)